# SQL Dynamic Self Cross Join using TSql

Tags: sql, cross-join

I have a table that has data like this

```
Group    Value  
1        A  
1        B  
1        C  
2        F  
2        G  
3        J
3        K
```

I want to join all members of one group to all members of each of the other groups into a single column like this:

```
AFJ
AFK
AGJ
AGK
BFJ
BFK
BGJ
BGK
CFJ
CFK
CGJ
CGK
```

There can be n number of groups and n number of values

Thank you

Comment: Which SQL database software are you using?  Different databases have different syntax and capabilities.

Comment: Using Microsoft TSql. thank you

Answer (score 2):

SQL does not offer many options for such a query.  The one standard method is a recursive CTE.  Other methods would involve recursive functions or stored procedures.

The following is an example of a recursive CTE that solves this problem:

```
with groups as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'f'), (2, 'g'), (3, 'h'), (3, 'k')
           ) v(g, val)
     ),
     cte as (
      select 1 as groupid, val, 1 as lev
      from groups
      where g = 1
      union all
      select cte.groupid + 1, cte.val + g.val, lev + 1
      from cte join
           groups g
           on g.g = cte.groupid + 1
     )
select val
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over () as max_lev
      from cte
     ) cte
where lev = max_lev
order by 1;
```

Some databases that support recursive CTEs don't use the `recursive` keyword.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b64abbcc7b79c96d3797f7d4203bcff9).

Comment: As always, good stuff.  Now that the OP has identified the db, I managed to get this to work by removing the word recursive, and forcing a conversion of val to be varchar(MAX) (e.g., val=CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), val) in the first line of the cte).

Comment: Thank you. This will work for me or I might do the same thing in C# which I usually prefer when things get more involved. I will keep this solution in my Library, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to consider gaps between the groups, i.e. Group 1, then no 2, then 3.

```
with t(Grp, val) as (
    select 1,        'A'  from dual
    union all
    select 1,        'B'    from dual
    union all
    select 1,        'C'    from dual
    union all
    select 2,        'F'    from dual
    union all
    select 2,        'G'    from dual
    union all
    select 3,        'J'  from dual
    union all
    select 3,        'K'  from dual
)

, grpIndexes as (
    SELECT ROWNUM indx
         , grp
     FROM (select distinct          
                  grp
             from t)
)

, Grps as (
    select t.*
         , grpIndexes.indx
      from t
     inner join grpIndexes
        on grpIndexes.grp = t.grp
)

, rt(val, indx, lvl) as (
    select val
         , indx
         , 0 as lvl
      from Grps
     where indx = (select min(indx) from Grps)
  union all
    select previous.val || this.val as val
         , this.indx
         , previous.lvl + 1 as lvl
      from rt previous
         , Grps this
     where this.indx = (select min(indx) from Grps where indx > previous.indx)
       and previous.indx <> (select max(indx) from Grps)
)

select val
  from rt
 where lvl = (select max(lvl) from rt)
  order by val
;
```

Note that I renamed the columns because Group and Value are reserved words.